# How to remove opacity animation in SwiftUI NavigationLink

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, navigationlink

When tapping on a NavigationLink, it reduces the opacity slightly. Is there a way to disable this. I tried using `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` but that didn't have the desired effect.

It is embedded in a scrollView (preferred over List for customizability):

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(items){ item in
        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()){
            HStack{
                Text("title")
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: continuous)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mena opactiy of the Button?

Comment: @davidev Not exactly. Just the opacity animation that occurs when a Navigation Link is tapped.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is possible solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Use custom button style that just returns label view (w/o highlight effect)

```
struct FlatLinkStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
    }
}
```

and

```
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()){
        HStack{
            Text("title")
            Spacer()
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
        }
        .padding()
    }.buttonStyle(FlatLinkStyle())     // << here !!
```

Comment: works in Xcode 12 and iOS 14.2 also. Thanks