# How to use a ContextMenu with a NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a `NavigationLink` with an attached `.contextMenu` modifier. Note that the `NavigationLink` is inside of a `ForEach` which is inside of a `LazyHStack` which is inside of a `ScrollView`. (I'm creating a horizontal scrolling row of "cards", much like many Apple apps.)

Now, both the navigation and the context menu work; if I single-tap, it navigates to the view I specify and if I long-press it presents a context menu. **The issue is that the context menu is focused on a highlighted grey view due to the navigation link highlighting.**

[image: Screenshot of issue]

I considered removing the highlighting of the navigation link via a view modifier to no avail. The grey highlight still applies to the context menu view.

```
.onAppear {
    UITableViewCell.appearance().selectionStyle = .none
    UITableView.appearance().allowsSelection = false
}
```

**So, how can I have a view that is both navigatable on tap as well as presents a context menu focused on the view when a long-press gesture is triggered?** Note that I am not trying to have a `NavigationLink` inside a `ContextMenu` (as many questions seem to be asking); I am trying to have a `ContextMenu` attached to a `NavigationLink`.

Answer (score 2):

By provided description I assume the solution will be to activate `NavigationLink` programmatically on tap, like (pseudo-code):

```
Card()
  .onTapGesture {
     activeCard = item
  }
  .contextMenu {
     // ...
  }
  .background(
     NavigationLink(destination: SomeView(), tag: item, selection: $activeCard) {
       EmptyView()
     }
  )
```

See next for complete example https://stackoverflow.com/a/58898046/12299030.

Comment: Hello, I was aware of a similar solution, though it feels quite a bit hacky to me. Moments ago I actually just found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62311089/2060140) that accomplishes what I want (by applying a custom styling--`PlainButtonStyle` does not seem to work). Edit: I see the other solution (preferable to me) was also provided by you. Kudos to you.

Comment: )) that is possible alternate... without provided code it is hard to guess.